# without speaking vs without talking

Tags: word-usage

TEXT.
The writer and his mother
sat in silence.
Question.
The writer and his mother sat
without ----
(1) speaking
(2) talking
Which one should be used ?
Why ?

Comment: Whichever one conveys the "mood" you wish to convey.

Comment: Define "*should*".

Answer (score 1):

I think 'talking' should be used here.

As speak is more formal than talk and the conversation here is between the writer and his mother, so it is informal meeting.

2- Speak usually only focuses on the person who is producing the words:

He spoke about the importance of taking exercise and having a good diet.

Talk focuses on a speaker and at least one listener, and can mean ‘have a conversation’:

I hope I can meet you to talk about my plans for the company.

Check this sight for more information :
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speak-or-talk

Comment: Although my first inclination would be "speaking" in this instance ("without talking" to me would suggest not speaking to each other, while "without speaking" suggests total silence; i.e., having no conversation with anyone), you nevertheless make a compelling argument for your position. +1 for a thoughtful, well documented answer.

Comment: How is speak more formal than talk?  Can you justify this assertion?

Answer (score -1):

If the pair are simply sitting there waiting, and have nothing really to talk about, they're "not talking". If, on the other hand, they're avoiding talking to each other (eg, they're angry with each other), they're "not speaking".

Answer (score -1):

Speak or talk?
from English Grammar Today
Speak and talk: uses
The verbs speak and talk both generally mean ‘say words’, but there are some small differences in how they are used. Speak is more formal than talk.

Compare
I need to speak to you.

Formal. It is possible that:

– the speaker does not know you very well.

– this is in a formal setting, such as work.

– what the person has to say is important/serious.

I need to talk to you.

Informal. It is possible that:

– the speaker is your friend.

– the speaker is someone you don’t know very well, but what they have to say is informal.

We usually use speak for more formal presentations and lectures, and talk for more informal ones:

Dr Graham Foster will speak about the history of the region.

Kyle is going to talk us through the benefits of the software and then Liz will talk about the marketing plan.

Check this site for more information : 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speak-or-talk